# VeriSign G5 Root Certificate - PayPal IPN

Tags: ssl-certificate

We're using Windows Server 2008 R2 and IIS. We need to make sure that we can send `POST` requests to the PayPal IPN sandbox URL:

- https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
- [SSL Report: sandbox.paypal.com](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sandbox.paypal.com%2Fcgi-bin%2Fwebscr)

We're trying to use the [PayPal SSL Certificate Upgrade Microsite](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&widgetview=true&id=FAQ1766&viewlocale=en_US&direct=en) but we need help.

I'm pretty sure our SSL certificates support SHA-256 ([example](https://www.wtshop.co.uk/customer_account.asp)). So we're looking at:

> 2. **Discontinue use of the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate**  In accordance with industry standards, PayPal will no longer honor secure connections that require the VeriSign G2 Root Certificate for trust validation. Only secure connection requests that are expecting our certificate/trust chain to be signed by the G5 Root Certificate will result in successful secure connections.

In the certificate hierarchy on the server (in IIS) I can see this for one of our certificates:

- Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
- ...Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
- ......Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
- .........[The name of our certificate in IIS]

When I go to:

- mmc
- File > Add/remove snap-in
- Certificates (Local Computer)
- Trusted Root Certification Authorities
- Certificates

I can see both:

1. Go Daddy Class 2 Certification Authority
2. VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5

On the PayPal microsite it says:

> confirm that the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate is in your keystore

I think it is, based on bullet number 2 above. There is a PDF document: [2015 Merchant Security System Upgrade Guide (U.K. English)](https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/resources/sites/PAYPAL/content/live/FAQ/1000/FAQ1766/en_US/2015%20Merchant%20Security%20System%20Upgrade%20Guide%20(U.K.%20English).pdf) linked to from the microsite that says:

> If the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate has not been downloaded to replace the G2 Root Certificate, you may see error messages similar to the following: SSL handshake error

We are getting this error message: `error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure`.

It then says:

> Update your software to the latest version that supports SHA-256

What software..?

> If a keystore is used for certificate validation/authentication, install the VeriSign G5 Root Certificate into your keystore.

How do I know if a keystore is used for certificate validation/authentication..?

> Obtain a VeriSign G5 Root Certificate

Doesn't the fact that **VeriSign Class 3 Public Primary Certification Authority - G5** appears in our **Trusted Root Certification Authorities > Certificates** mean that we already have it..?

So my question really is, given the information about our server outlined above, what do we need to do on our server to make sure we can send `POST` requests to the PayPal IPN sandbox URL..?

Comment: Have you checked your SSL? It's a G2, not a G5 from what I see in the tests. See `https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=https://www.wtshop.co.uk`. It shows all G2 certs. PayPal upgraded to G5 `https://devblog.paypal.com/paypal-ssl-certificate-changes/` and no longer supports G2.

Comment: Thanks @Gmck, that PayPal link doesn't seem to work. So... Are you saying that we need to scrap all our SSL certs, and buy new G5 certs..??? I don't really understand all this stuff, but I need to get this PayPal IPN working, so I need to know what to do next...

Comment: I have not used GoDaddy certs, but they should allow you to re-issue the G5 cert at no charge. You have to make a new key and submit a new CSR in most cases, then select the SHA256 version of the certs in the the GoDaddy panel. I am sure GoDaddy support can guide you if all else fails.